# Wrong OAuth 2.0 JWT token for Google APIs using .NET Core and X.509 certificate

Tags: c#, admob, google-oauth, service-accounts, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to make requests to the [Google APIs AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest) services. This API requires the new OAuth 2.0 authentication process which for the Service-to-service integration, is a two steps process: 1) Create a local and signed JWT and send it to Google 2) Retrieve a token to query the API. I've been testing creating the JWT manually and by using the official libraries but they end-up throwing same error:

"*The service admob has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Unauthorized. Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.*"

**Code using official library**

```
// path to the .p12 certificate
var privateKeyFilePath = Path.Combine(X509_KEY_FILE_NAME);
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyFilePath, "MySecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
CertificateCredentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(emailAccountId)
{
    ProjectId = "MyProjectId",
    Scopes = new[] { AdMobService.Scope.AdmobReadonly },
}.FromCertificate(certificate));
...
var adMobService = new AdMobService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = CertificateCredentials,
    ApplicationName = "MyProjectId",
});
// line that throws the error
var accountsResponse = await adMobService.Accounts.List().ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

var account = accountsResponse.Account.FirstOrDefault();
```

**Code using a locally signed token:**

```
// we reuse X509 loaded previously
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);

var jwtHeader = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials)
    {
        { "kid", kid }
    };

var jwtPayload = new JwtPayload(
        issuer: emailAccountId,
        audience: GoogleAuthConsts.TokenUrl,
        claims: new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim("scope", AdMobService.Scope.AdmobReadonly),
        },
        notBefore: null,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
        issuedAt: DateTime.Now);

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwt = handler.WriteToken(new JwtSecurityToken(jwtHeader, jwtPayload));

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" },
        { "assertion", jwt }
    };
var httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(GoogleAuthConsts.OidcTokenUrl, httpContent, cancellationToken);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);

var TokenResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseContent);

var httpClientAdMob = new HttpClient();
httpClientAdMob.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", TokenResponse.AccessToken);
var responseAdMob = await httpClientAdMob.GetAsync("https://admob.googleapis.com/v1/accounts", cancellationToken);

if (responseAdMob.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
// line that throws the error
    var contentAdMob = await responseAdMob.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

By removing extra values for the JWT Payload as "Kid" doesn't seems to affect.

I tried the official release of the *Google.Apis.Auth* and *Google.Apis.AdMob.v1* libraries. Alongside a manual creation of a JWT to retrieve the access token from *Google OAuth's token* endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the doucmentation [Authorization](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/how-tos/authorizing) you will notice it states

[image]

You need to use Oauth2 service account authorization isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of try and error, I came with two possible solutions:

**1)** Using the JSON of an *OAuth Client* of "Web" type. These parameters in the JSON are inside an "installed" json property:

```
var jsonWebInstalledCredentialsPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location)!, "my-file.json");
var installedCredentials = await GoogleClientSecrets.FromFileAsync(jsonWebInstalledCredentialsPath, cancellationToken);
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    installedCredentials.Secrets,
    new[] { AdMobService.Scope.AdmobReadonly },
    Environment.UserName,
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("Store"));

var oauthService = new Oauth2Service(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "MyProject",
});

var adMobService = new AdMobService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = oauthService.HttpClientInitializer,
    ApplicationName = "MyProject",
});

var accountsResponse = await adMobService.Accounts.List().ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

var account = accountsResponse.Account.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CurrencyCode == "USD");
```

**2)** Using a .p12 file from a Service Account by creating a *ServiceAccountCredential* object and then pass it to the *OAuthService* as a *GoogleCredential*:

```
var privateKeyFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location)!, "my-project-keys.p12");
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var serviceCredentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("project-backend-service@project-xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
{
    Scopes = new[] { AdMobService.Scope.AdmobReadonly },
    UseJwtAccessWithScopes = true,
}.FromCertificate(certificate));


var googleCredentials = GoogleCredential.FromServiceAccountCredential(serviceCredentials);

var t1_oauthService = new Oauth2Service(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = googleCredentials,
    ApplicationName = "MyProject",
});

var t1_adMobService = new AdMobService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = t1_oauthService.HttpClientInitializer,
    ApplicationName = "MyProject",
});

var t1_accountsResponse = await adMobService.Accounts.List().ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
```

All requests are working and I can get valid access Tokens by calling  **credentials.Token** which returns a *TokenResponse* that I can attach to any HttpClient request.